# How to make width of a column fit to its contents in IE9 compatibility mode?

Tags: html, css, ie-compatibility-mode

I have the following table in my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<style type="text/css">
    table, td, tr, th{
        border:1px;
    }

    .onepx{
        width:1px;
    }
</style>


<div style="max-width:700px;">
    <table>
        <tr><td colspan="2">this is a loooooooooooooooong text</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="onepx">a:</td><td>b</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="onepx">c:</td><td>d</td></tr>
    </table>
<div>
```

I want the first column width in the second and third row to just fit the content length (that is why I put width="1px" there). In the mean while, I want to table width to just fit the length of the longest content in the table (which is the first row) instead of spanning to the max-width of its bounding div.

It works in Firefox and IE9 with compatibility mode turned off as shown below.

[image: firefox]

However, in IE 9 compatibility mode it does not work as expected, as shown.

[image: ie compatibility mode]

For some reason, I cannot turn off compatibility mode in IE9. So is there a way to style the table as in compatibility mode?

Thanks in advance.

PS. I asked a similar question without emphasizing the IE9 compatibility mode. This question is raised after getting the information from the previous question. I am not sure if I should merge this question into the previous one as there is new requirement. Let me know if there is any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So looking at what you've provided, if that's how it's set up in your file, you're working in strict mode and missing the opening  and .

As far as changing IE9 mode, select F12 and you can change the browser and document mode.

Also, don't forget to add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >` to your head.

The table style should be moved to CSS.

You could also try:

Table:

```
<table class="fixed">
    <col width="10px" />
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.fixed { table-layout: fixed; }
table.fixed td { overflow: hidden; }
```